# Concatenate strings returned from functions in bash

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to extract a version string from a text file with contains the major, minor and patch elements of the specific version.

This file is named `versioninfo.txt` and its contents are like the following:

```
MAJOR 2
MINOR 0
PATCH 0
```

I'm writing a bash script to extract the values from that file and generate a string like `v2.0.0` but I'm struggling when building the complete version string.

This is the bash script I wrote

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function extractVersionElement() {
    line=$(sed "${1}q;d" versioninfo.txt)
    version="${line#* }"
    echo "${version}"
}

function extractVersion() {
    major="$(extractVersionElement 1)"
    minor="$(extractVersionElement 2)"
    patch="$(extractVersionElement 3)"

    echo "major: ${major}"
    echo "minor: ${minor}"
    echo "patch: ${patch}"
}

version="$(extractVersion)"
echo "$version"
```

Which outputs, correctly reading the single version elements:

```
$ ./extract_version.sh
major: 2
minor: 0
patch: 0
```

Changing the script to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function extractVersionElement() {
    line=$(sed "${1}q;d" versioninfo.txt)
    version="${line#* }"
    echo "${version}"
}

function extractVersion() {
    major="$(extractVersionElement 1)"
    minor="$(extractVersionElement 2)"
    patch="$(extractVersionElement 3)"

    # Here I try to create the complete version string
    echo "v${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
}

version="$(extractVersion)"
echo "$version"
```

Outputs the following, truncating the output:

```
$ ./extract_version.sh
.0
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

---

**Working script**

The problems were caused by `\r` at the end of each line. This is the working script which solves the problem:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function extractVersionElement() {
    # read the nth line of the versioninfo file
    line=$(sed "${1}q;d" versioninfo.txt)

    # remove \r and \n from the string which were causing
    # problems when creating the final version string
    line=${line//[$'\t\r\n']}

    # extract the version after the space
    version="${line#* }"

    # return the read version
    echo "${version}"
}

function extractVersion() {
    major="$(extractVersionElement 1)"
    minor="$(extractVersionElement 2)"
    patch="$(extractVersionElement 3)"

    # combine the three version elements into one version string
    echo "v${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
}

version="$(extractVersion)"
echo "$version"
```

Comment: Do you have MSWin line ends in the input file?

Comment: Now that you mention that yes, I didn't even think about that. Looking at the other question linked above, I'll try to change my `sed` call to remove the trailing `\r`

Comment: Use a tool like `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Comment: Since I'll be running this script in a CI/CD environment I want to be sure to be as compatible as possible, without using external tools. I ended up using variable expansion to remove all `\n`, `\r` and `\t`. I'll update my question with the working code.